# JRebel suddenly destroyed server startup

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, jrebel

JRebel suddenly destroyed my server startup (weblogic) via Eclipse. Without JRebel enabled on that server, it starts up just fine. With JRebel, now all the sudden all we get is an error message in the console saying:

*'trading-repos' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

JRebel has worked flawless until today. So not sure what is happening here. My PATH seems fine.

Comment: 2 Screenshots of my Eclipse.

http://tinypic.com/r/wlwzma/8

http://tinypic.com/r/2rm9kz8/8

Answer (score 1):

Can you paste the startup command line here? 
Enable JRebel logging and search it for any errors.

http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/learn/sending-log/

If nothing is out of ordinary, then I suggest you contact support@zeroturnaround.com (Don't forget to send the log.)

Comment: And where do I find the startup command? I start it via Eclipse --> mark the server --> right click --> start.

Comment: I turned on JREbel log and tried to restart. But JRebel log has no entries since 2014-09-18.

Comment: Think I found the start script. But I find nothing there regarding anything about no "trading-repos"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the start script I beleive

```
@ECHO OFF
@REM WARNING: This file is created by the Configuration Wizard.
@REM Any changes to this script may be lost when adding extensions to this configuration.
SETLOCAL
@REM --- Start Functions ---
GOTO :ENDFUNCTIONS
:stopAll
    @REM We separate the stop commands into a function so we are able to use the trap command in Unix (calling a function) to stop these services
    if NOT "X%ALREADY_STOPPED%"=="X" (
        GOTO :EOF
    )
    @REM STOP DERBY (only if we started it)
    if "%DERBY_FLAG%"=="true" (
        echo Stopping Derby server...
        call "%WL_HOME%\common\derby\bin\stopNetworkServer.cmd"  >"%DOMAIN_HOME%\derbyShutdown.log" 2>&1 
        echo Derby server stopped.
    )
    set ALREADY_STOPPED=true
GOTO :EOF
:classCaching
    echo Class caching enabled...
    set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dlaunch.main.class=%SERVER_CLASS% -Dlaunch.class.path="%CLASSPATH%" -Dlaunch.complete=weblogic.store.internal.LockManagerImpl -cp %WL_HOME%\server\lib\pcl2.jar
    set SERVER_CLASS=com.oracle.classloader.launch.Launcher
GOTO :EOF
:ENDFUNCTIONS
@REM --- End Functions ---
@REM *************************************************************************
@REM This script is used to start WebLogic Server for this domain.
@REM 
@REM To create your own start script for your domain, you can initialize the
@REM environment by calling @USERDOMAINHOME\setDomainEnv.
@REM 
@REM setDomainEnv initializes or calls commEnv to initialize the following variables:
@REM 
@REM BEA_HOME       - The BEA home directory of your WebLogic installation.
@REM JAVA_HOME      - Location of the version of Java used to start WebLogic
@REM                  Server.
@REM JAVA_VENDOR    - Vendor of the JVM (i.e. BEA, HP, IBM, Sun, etc.)
@REM PATH           - JDK and WebLogic directories are added to system path.
@REM WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH
@REM                - Classpath needed to start WebLogic Server.
@REM PATCH_CLASSPATH - Classpath used for patches
@REM PATCH_LIBPATH  - Library path used for patches
@REM PATCH_PATH     - Path used for patches
@REM WEBLOGIC_EXTENSION_DIRS - Extension dirs for WebLogic classpath patch
@REM JAVA_VM        - The java arg specifying the VM to run.  (i.e.
@REM                - server, -hotspot, etc.)
@REM USER_MEM_ARGS  - The variable to override the standard memory arguments
@REM                  passed to java.
@REM PRODUCTION_MODE - The variable that determines whether Weblogic Server is started in production mode.
@REM DERBY_HOME - Derby home directory.
@REM DERBY_CLASSPATH
@REM                - Classpath needed to start Derby.
@REM 
@REM Other variables used in this script include:
@REM SERVER_NAME    - Name of the weblogic server.
@REM JAVA_OPTIONS   - Java command-line options for running the server. (These
@REM                  will be tagged on to the end of the JAVA_VM and
@REM                  MEM_ARGS)
@REM CLASS_CACHE    - Enable class caching of system classpath.
@REM 
@REM For additional information, refer to "Managing Server Startup and Shutdown for Oracle WebLogic Server"
@REM  (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13708/overview.htm).
@REM *************************************************************************
@REM Call setDomainEnv here.
set DOMAIN_HOME=C:\ORACLE\Middleware\user_projects\domains\test3
for %%i in ("%DOMAIN_HOME%") do set DOMAIN_HOME=%%~fsi
call "%DOMAIN_HOME%\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd" %*
set SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS%
set SAVE_CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%
@REM Start Derby
set DERBY_DEBUG_LEVEL=0
if "%DERBY_FLAG%"=="true" (
    call "%WL_HOME%\common\derby\bin\startNetworkServer.cmd"  >"%DOMAIN_HOME%\derby.log" 2>&1 
)
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS%
set SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS=
set CLASSPATH=%SAVE_CLASSPATH%
set SAVE_CLASSPATH=
if "%PRODUCTION_MODE%"=="true" (
    set WLS_DISPLAY_MODE=Production
) else (
    set WLS_DISPLAY_MODE=Development
)
if NOT "%WLS_USER%"=="" (
    set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dweblogic.management.username=%WLS_USER%
)
if NOT "%WLS_PW%"=="" (
    set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dweblogic.management.password=%WLS_PW%
)
if NOT "%MEDREC_WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH%"=="" (
    if NOT "%CLASSPATH%"=="" (
        set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%MEDREC_WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH%
    ) else (
        set CLASSPATH=%MEDREC_WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH%
    )
)
echo .
echo .
echo JAVA Memory arguments: %MEM_ARGS%
echo .
echo WLS Start Mode=%WLS_DISPLAY_MODE%
echo .
echo CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%
echo .
echo PATH=%PATH%
echo .
echo ***************************************************
echo *  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
echo *  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
echo *  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
echo *  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
echo ***************************************************
@REM CLASS CACHING
if "%CLASS_CACHE%"=="true" (
    CALL :classCaching
)
@REM START WEBLOGIC
echo starting weblogic with Java version:
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_VM% -version
if "%WLS_REDIRECT_LOG%"=="" (
    echo Starting WLS with line:
    echo %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% -Djava.security.policy=%WL_HOME%\server\lib\weblogic.policy %JAVA_OPTIONS% %PROXY_SETTINGS% %SERVER_CLASS%
    %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% -Djava.security.policy=%WL_HOME%\server\lib\weblogic.policy %JAVA_OPTIONS% %PROXY_SETTINGS% %SERVER_CLASS%
) else (
    echo Redirecting output from WLS window to %WLS_REDIRECT_LOG%
    %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% -Djava.security.policy=%WL_HOME%\server\lib\weblogic.policy %JAVA_OPTIONS% %PROXY_SETTINGS% %SERVER_CLASS%  >"%WLS_REDIRECT_LOG%" 2>&1 
)
CALL :stopAll
popd
@REM Exit this script only if we have been told to exit.
if "%doExitFlag%"=="true" (
    exit
)
ENDLOCAL
```